# Prevent duplication with webpack splitChunks

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm struggling with splitChunks and I can't seem to find any suitable answers on similar posted questions. Perhaps my approach is incorrect.

I would like to remove an array of common modules from my core bundle (*ui.js*) and put them in a separate file (*inline.js*).

**webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    inline: [
        './src/utils/namespace/namespace.js',
        './src/core/pubsub/pubsub.js',
        './src/core/rum/rum.js',
    ],
    ui: './src/ui.js',
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist/js' ),
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            inline: {
                name: 'inline',
                test: 'inline',
                chunks: 'all',
                enforce: true
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

**HTML Page:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            // I load the code from inline.js here
        </script>
        <script>
            // Another small inline script outside of webpack
            RUM.mark( 'js_inline_loaded' ); // RUM is not defined
        </script>
        <script src="ui.js" defer></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The above seems to work as the code is split correctly into their respective files but the inline code does not initialise straight away because it's pushed to an array called **webpackJsonp**.

This means with **RUM** defined in *inline.js*, when it is called straight after the include, it errors as it is not defined.

Is there a simple option I'm missing to remove the webpackJsonp array?

Am I doing something silly or is there a different approach I should take like [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: webpackJsonp is how webpack find all your chunks (it is intentional). Try splitting up the runtime chunk, add runtimeChunk: true inside optimization.

Comment: @PlayMa256 - Adding runtimeChunk: { name: 'inline' } seems to remove the webpackJsonp wrapper but it still doesn't self invoke so RUM is still undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this hasn't had much response. After trying to understand the documentation and testing every configuration option possible, I've come up with a workaround so I will post it incase anyone has similar problems. Please bear in mind, this is a workaround and I will update if I ever find the right approach.

My optimisation configuration object now looks like the following:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: { name: 'inline-manifest' },
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            common: {
                chunks: 'all',
                name: 'inline-commons',
                test: 'inline',
                enforce: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate three files. **inline.js**, **inline-commons.js**, **inline-manifest.js**.

These are all included as part of the 'inline' page script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            // Load inline,js, inline-commons.js & inline-manifest.js here
        </script>
        <script>
            // Another small inline script outside of webpack
            RUM.mark( 'js_inline_loaded' ); // RUM is now defined
        </script>
        <script src="ui.js" defer></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

**inline-commons** - contains all of the code shared between *inline.js* and *ui.js*

**inline-manifest** - contains the webpack bootstrap loader to initialise the scripts

**inline** - contains the modules unique to *inline.js*

Like I say, this is a workaround so please tread carefully. If anyone knows the right approach, please feel free to post an update.

Comment: Are you still going with this approach? Sounds like what I'm trying to do right now.